# CSS styling - ignore hidden elements?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using some code to hide breadcrumbs on certain page IDs in Wordpress.  I've styled the "breadcrumbs" div with a background colour and some padding.  My problem is that the  still appears on the pages where the breadcrumb trail is hidden. Is there a way to style the CSS differently to solve this?
If I use a class rather than an ID,

```
<div id="breadcrumbs">
    <?php 
        $ids = array( 2366, 40, 16, 7 );
        if ( ! is_page() || ! in_array( get_the_ID(), $ids ) ) {
            bcn_display();
        } 
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: And your question is? o_o

Comment: Side note...are you sure your `||` shouldn't be an `&&`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your breadcrumb div within your `if` statement...

```
<?php 
    $ids = array( 2366, 40, 16, 7 );

    if ( ! is_page() || ! in_array( get_the_ID(), $ids ) ) {
        echo '<div id="breadcrumbs">';
        bcn_display();
        echo '</div>';
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you - I should have known that.  Much appreciated.